# PowerBI DAX Measure to return 1 for all the items in category if any item in category has result 1

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need measure (or maybe calculated column) which will return 1 in the column called Final when any of the item Table2[name] per category (Table1[Category]) is 1. So even if there is just one item in the category that has result 1 it returns 1 for all of them in the same category and 0 when all the items in the category have result 0. Hope the example below is clear.

| Table1[Category] | Table2[name] | Result | Final |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A:1 | 0 | 1 |
| A | A:2 | 1 | 1 |
| A | A:3 | 0 | 1 |
| B | B:1 | 0 | 0 |
| B | B:2 | 0 | 0 |
| C | C:1 | 1 | 1 |
| C | C:2 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Please don't start with "Hey guys" (it's not inclusive) or any socialising. It is not necessary, just focus on asking the question and providing sufficient context and information. Most people want to spend their time on SO efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Using variables you can access the Category to filter on the table and obtain the `MAX` result.

### Calculation: Calculated Column

```
Final =
VAR CurrentCat = [Table1[Category]]]
VAR MaxResult =
    MAXX ( FILTER ( 'Table', [Table1[Category]]] = CurrentCat ), [Result] )
RETURN
    IF ( MaxResult = 1, 1, 0 )
```

### Output

| Table1[Category] | Table2[name] | Result | Final |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A:1 | 0 | 1 |
| A | A:2 | 1 | 1 |
| A | A:3 | 0 | 1 |
| B | B:1 | 0 | 0 |
| B | B:2 | 0 | 0 |
| C | C:1 | 1 | 1 |
| C | C:2 | 0 | 1 |